# How to fold the foldable phone in emulator?

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

I have created the Foldable phone emulator from AVD. But, I'm unable to fold the screen to test out the foldable feature and test my flutter project.

How do we fold the foldable phone emulator to show the folded region only?

Comment: There should be one book type icon(open/close depending upon emulator state) , below rotation icon on side menu in the emulator, use that to expand/collapse emulator

Comment: Thanks I got it. You can put it as answer, I'll aprove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be one book type icon(open/close depending upon emulator state) , below rotation icon on side menu in the emulator, use that to expand/collapse emulator.

[image]